# VBA - allow duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function (within a program that loops through multiple files) that grabs values in a column and prints them to one file. It is omitting duplicates and **I need it to include duplicate values**. I am new to VBA so I cannot even pinpoint where it is not allowing for these duplicates.

If you have a solution for allowing duplicates or can even just help me pinpoint where it is not allowing duplicates,that would be of great help. Please help.

Here is the function that gets the values that I believe is also not allowing for duplicate values:

```
'(8)
'get column values
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim theValue As String
    Dim splitValues As Variant

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dataRange = ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
    ' If there are no values in this column then return an empty dictionary
    ' If there are no values in this column, the dataRange will start at the row
    ' *above* ch and end at ch
    If (dataRange.Row = (ch.Row - 1)) And (dataRange.Rows.count = 2) And (Trim(ch.Value) = "") Then
        GoTo Exit_Function
    End If

    For Each cell In dataRange.Cells
        theValue = Trim(cell.Value)
        If Len(theValue) = 0 Then
            theValue = " "
        End If
            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ";")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If
            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ",")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If

            If Not dict.exists(theValue) Then
            dict.Add theValue, theValue
        End If
    Next cell
Exit_Function:
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function
```

FULL CODE:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim f As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, hc4 As Range, d As Range
    Dim TDS As Range
    Dim hc12 As Range, n As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")
    Set hc4 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("A1"), "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2

    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)
            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet

            With WB
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                    'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'if no items are under the CUTTING TOOL header
                        StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "  "
                    End If
                'Else find CUTTING WHEEL on the source sheet
                ElseIf Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING WHEEL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING WHEEL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                    'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                    'if no items are under the CUTTING TOOL header
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "  "
                End If
                Else
                    'if no CUTTING TOOL header is found on the sheet
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO CUTTING TOOL PRESENT"
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc3 = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'if no items are under the HOLDER header
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = " "
                    End If
                'Else find WHEEL ARBOR on the source sheet
                ElseIf Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="WHEEL ARBOR", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc3 = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="WHEEL ARBOR", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'if no items are under the HOLDER header
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = " "
                    End If
                'Else find HOLDER / ARBOR # on the source sheet
                ElseIf Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER / ARBOR #", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc3 = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER / ARBOR #", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'if no items are under the HOLDER header
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = " "
                    End If

                Else
                    'if no HOLDER header is found on the sheet
                    StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO HOLDER PRESENT"
                End If
'(5)
                'print the file name to Column 4
                StartSht.Cells(i, 4) = objFile.Name

                With ws
                'Print TDS name by searching for header
                    If Not ws.Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                        Set TDS = ws.Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
                    Else
                        'print the file name wihtout the extension
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = GetFilenameWithoutExtension(objFile.Name)
                    End If
                    i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                End With

                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
'(7)
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'brings the viewer to the top of the masterfile
End Sub
'(8)
'get column values
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim theValue As String
    Dim splitValues As Variant

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dataRange = ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
    ' If there are no values in this column then return an empty dictionary
    ' If there are no values in this column, the dataRange will start at the row
    ' *above* ch and end at ch
    If (dataRange.Row = (ch.Row - 1)) And (dataRange.Rows.count = 2) And (Trim(ch.Value) = "") Then
        GoTo Exit_Function
    End If

    For Each cell In dataRange.Cells
        theValue = Trim(cell.Value)
        If Len(theValue) = 0 Then
            theValue = " "
        End If
            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ";")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If
            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ",")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If

            If Not dict.exists(theValue) Then
            dict.Add theValue, theValue
        End If
    Next cell
Exit_Function:
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function
'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        'copy cell value if it contains some string "holder" or "cutting tool"
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
        'If InStr(c.Value, sHeader) <> 0 Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function
'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
'(12)
'get the file name without the extension
Function GetFilenameWithoutExtension(ByVal FileName)
  Dim Result, i
  Result = FileName
  i = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
  If (i > 0) Then
    Result = Mid(FileName, 1, i - 1)
  End If
  GetFilenameWithoutExtension = Result
End Function
```

Comment: The entire code was written to specifically not allow duplicates. That is why a dictionary was used. You would need to rewrite a bit to allow duplicates.

Comment: Dictionary Objects can not have duplicate keys

Comment: Then substitute the dictionary with an array

Comment: @AbeGold okay,  I was thinking that was the issue but hoping there would be a smaller fix. Do you think you could help me with reworking the code or have any tips for me? I really need this to work soon

Comment: @Roland that is definitely the problem I have run in to. I have been trying to rework it as a sort of Array but I am not skilled in VBA and cannot get it to work anywhere near what it's supposed to do. Could you help me out with figuring out how to rewrite?

Comment: You need to replace the dictionary with an array. Then just add values to that array (you can make it dynamical, so it wouldn't be limited to a specified number of entries).

Comment: @EngJon sounds like a plan! Could you help me work through it or do you know of any helpful websites that would help me figure that out? I have been trying to look for some but they all seem to aim toward omitting duplicates

Comment: Get used to vba arrays (keyword: ReDim for dynamical arrays), try it out in another file (adding values, printing it, etc.). Then redesign the code here by adapting the writing to a file with a loop through the array and not through a dictionary. Sorry, but you'd have to take some effort in order to make it work.

Comment: Using an array is the way to got. But: since you are not using the keys of your Dictionary but grabbing dict.items, you can add a counter in GetValues which increments with each loop. Concatenate the counter to the value to get a distinct key (dict.add theValue + counter, theValue). Not very nice, though.

Comment: @EngJon I created a function before that used a dictionary (probably in a way it is not supposed to be used) as objects and got the duplicate values. Do you think there is any way I can mesh the two together to get it to work? The reason I changed it is because it was grabbing a header whenever the file was empty since it was an object not a dictionary. http://pastie.org/10246928

Comment: As, in your posted code, the dictionary is just filled with key = value, you could introduce an index as a key for the dictionary. just increment the index for every value you add and then call the dictionary like `dict.Add index, theValue` edit: pretty much like the answer suggested by Prabu krishna

Comment: @Roland , sounds like it's worth a try! Where in my code would I put that? And would I have to code something for counter separately? Sorry, I've never used that before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without rewriting everything, just put an incrementing key in your dictionary and make sure you use the data dictionary value that is returned from your function and not the key.

```
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dataRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim theValue As String
Dim splitValues As Variant
Dim counter as Long
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set dataRange = ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
' If there are no values in this column then return an empty dictionary
' If there are no values in this column, the dataRange will start at the row
' *above* ch and end at ch
If (dataRange.Row = (ch.Row - 1)) And (dataRange.Rows.count = 2) And (Trim(ch.Value) = "") Then
    GoTo Exit_Function
End If

For Each cell In dataRange.Cells
    counter = counter + 1
    theValue = Trim(cell.Value)
    If Len(theValue) = 0 Then
        theValue = " "
    End If
        'exclude any info after ";"
        If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            splitValues = Split(theValue, ";")
            theValue = splitValues(0)
        End If
        'exclude any info after ","
        If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            splitValues = Split(theValue, ",")
            theValue = splitValues(0)
        End If

        If Not dict.exists(theValue) Then
        dict.Add counter, theValue
    End If
Next cell Exit_Function:
Set GetValues = dict 

End Function
```

Comment: This works beautifully. Could you explain why the data dictionary fixed it as opposed to the key? Thank you so much! @GELR

Comment: All the answers here follow the same idea: since you do not use the key, you can set it to a counter or any other unique value

Comment: @Roland Ah I see how that messed things up. Thanks! If by any chance you want to help me with one more little problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918113/vba-transfer-empty-cell-to-sheet

Comment: Or @GELR if you know how to fix empty cells, it's the last obstacle I have in getting this whole program to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918113/vba-transfer-empty-cell-to-sheet

Answer (score 1):

Replace the Getvalues function with the below code. it will work.

```
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim theValue As String
    Dim splitValues As Variant
    Dim icounter As Long

    icounter = 1
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dataRange = ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
    ' If there are no values in this column then return an empty dictionary
    ' If there are no values in this column, the dataRange will start at the row
    ' *above* ch and end at ch
    If (dataRange.Row = (ch.Row - 1)) And (dataRange.Rows.Count = 2) And (Trim(ch.Value) = "") Then
        GoTo Exit_Function
    End If

    For Each cell In dataRange.Cells
        theValue = Trim(cell.Value)
        If Len(theValue) = 0 Then
            theValue = " "
        End If
            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ";")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If
            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ",")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If


            dict.Add theValue, icounter

            icounter = icounter + 1

    Next cell
Exit_Function:
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function
```

Comment: Okay I put this in my code and I got a runtime error _This key is already associated with an element of this collection_ on the line `dict.Add theValue, icounter`. When I have gotten this before, what fixed it was putting a line before that one that said `If Not dict.exists(theValue) Then`. Would that work or do you have a different suggestion? @Prabukrishna

Comment: This also gave me back numbers not values so I'm not sure where that went wrong

Comment: switch `theValue` and `icounter` on that line